# Sequelize raw query update array of objects as replacements

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, rawsql

I am using sequelize (postgres) and I need to properly escape a query like this:

```sql
`
       UPDATE "Pets"
       SET "name" = CASE LOWER("name")
         ${input.pets
            .map((pet) => `WHEN '${pet.name.toLowerCase()}' THEN '${pet.newName}'`)
            .join('\n')}
          ELSE "name"
          END
        WHERE LOWER("name") IN(${input.pets
          .map((pet) => `'${pet.name.toLowerCase()}'`)
          .join(',')});
`
```

Sample `input.pets`:

```
[{ name: "rocky", newName: "leo" }]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this with replacements?

I have found a thread on github which suggested something like this:

```sql
let data = [ [ 252456, 1, 55, '0' ],
[ 357083, 1, 56, '0' ],
[ 316493, 1, 57, '0' ] ];

db.query(
  `INSERT INTO product (a, b) VALUES ${data.map(a => '(?)').join(',')};`,
  {
     replacements: data,
     type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
  }
);
```

However, a 2d array is being used here not an array of objects. Is there a way to access individual properties from the array? When I try something like this

```sql
`
       UPDATE "Pets"
       SET "name" = CASE LOWER("name")
         ${input.pets
            .map((_pet) => `WHEN ? THEN ?`)
            .join('\n')}
          ELSE "name"
          END
        WHERE LOWER("name") IN(${input.pets
          .map((_pet) => `?`)
          .join(',')});
`,
    { type: QueryTypes.UPDATE, replacements: input.pets },
```

The first `?` turns out to be the whole object. Is there a way to access it's properties?
I also tried transforming `input.pets` into a 2d array but still couldn't get it to work as in example with insert above.

In advance thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const names = input.pets.map((pet) => pet.name);
    const newNames = input.pets.map((pet) => pet.newName);

`
        UPDATE "Pets"
        SET "name" = CASE LOWER("name")
          ${names.map((_) => `WHEN LOWER(:names) THEN :newNames`).join('\n')}
              ELSE "name"
              END
        WHERE LOWER("name") IN(${names.map((_) => `LOWER(:names)`).join(',')});
`,
      { replacements: { names, newNames } },
```

This works. In cases like this it's better to work with simpler data structures. Another option I found is using `sequelize.escape()` built-in function, but it's not documented so I decided not to

EDIT:
After some testing, this works but for only one object in the input

If the input looks something like this:

```
[
        { name: "rocky", newName: "fafik" }
        { name: "asd", newName: "qwerty" }
]
```

Then in resut I get queries like this:

```
WHEN LOWER('rocky', 'asd') THEN 'fafik', 'qwerty'
WHEN LOWER('rocky', 'asd') THEN 'fafik', 'qwerty'
```

So it doesn't loop over arrays. Still the problem remains, how to access individual properties, whether from array or an object?

EDIT2: FINAL ANSWER

```js
sequelize.query(
  `
    UPDATE "Pets"
    SET "name" = CASE LOWER("name")
      ${input.pets.map(() => `WHEN ? THEN ?`).join('\n')}
         ELSE "name"
         END
    WHERE LOWER("name") IN(?);
  `,
  {
    replacements: [
      ...input.pets.flatMap((x) => [x.name.toLocaleLowerCase(), x.newName]),
      input.pets.map((x) => x.name.toLocaleLowerCase()),
    ],
  },
```